# Make Images Same Height and Define a Shared Total Width

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm racking my brain over here, trying to figure out how to make two completely different sized images share the same height, and have a combined total width of say 900px – where 900px is subject to change.

Imagine I've got a 900px `.container` and two randomly-sized images:

```
<main class="container">
  <div class="gallery">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x200" />
</main>
```

I've set up a [CodePen over here](http://codepen.io/realph/pen/EaXJxa).

How can I force those images to fit flush inside that 900px `.container`, while maintaining their aspect ratio, while also sharing the same height?

Any help with this would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just create a class and style it with the width and height you want to. Then add the class to the images and Eureka! `<img class="resize" src="XXXX" />`

Then define it in css:

`.resize {
height:XXXpx;
width:xxpx;
}`

If this does not work, you can always force the inline style tag:

`<img style="width:XXXpx;height:XXXpx;" src="XXXX" />`

Hope it helps!

Comment: I don't want to hard code any of the values in CSS, I would like it to work dynamically. Using some JS, perhaps...